# Jquery script considered as span

Tags: jquery

I have a strange problem with jquery selector, in fact it is considering a script as a span, because the following code is not working :

```
<span id="sp1">
    <script></script>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</span>
```

my selctor code is :

```
<script> 
    if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined'){
        $j =jQuery.noConflict();
    }
    $j(function() {             
        alert($j("#sp1 span:nth-child(1)").text());
        alert($j("#sp1 span:nth-child(2)").text());
    });
</script>
```

but it is returning the script as the first span, but i can't modify the code to take the 2nd and the third child, as the sample code above is replicated in a loop and in the other portion of code, there is no script in the span. How can i achieve this with no looping but with only the right selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Output that you are seeing is an expected one, since `:nth-child()` would select the nth child element regardless of the element nature. So in this context you should use `:nth-of-type()`

Try,

```
 alert($j("#sp1 span:nth-of-type(1)").text());
 alert($j("#sp1 span:nth-of-type(2)").text());
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4J5V2/)

Answer (score 3):

use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

```
$j(function() {             
    alert($j("#sp1 span:nth-of-type(1)").text());
    alert($j("#sp1 span:nth-of-type(2)").text());
});
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RsKR2/9/)